# Passing Cell Values into a combo box list

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to pass cells values into the list for a combo box in Excel.

I have created an array to pass the cell values into but they aren't getting to the combo box list when they are being called. I need the cell values to display as the drop down items and all that displays is the blank space:

```
Sub Clear_Invoice_Data()

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = Range("A1:A5").Value

    frmAddLineItem.ddlProduct.List = Arr    

End Sub
```

It is called by a button from a User form:

```
Private Sub cmdClearAll_Click()

    Call Button_Functions.Clear_Invoice_Data
    i = 18

End Sub
```

Pictures of problem: (no values)

[image: no elements]
[image: 5 elements]

Comment: This should work as expected. Can you show some more of your code?  This will have to be assigned *before* the `frmAddLineItem.Show` statement.

Comment: There isn't much more to show really that's the whole Sub. It's called by a button on a user form (Code Above)

Comment: Please put your code in the question. It's impossible to read it when you put it in a comment.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint on the assignment to debug it?

Comment: No, it doesnt break the array gets created but it has no values just the space. See above for pics

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked if you put a breakpoint on that line. If you don't know what a breakpoint is, you need to look it up and learn basics of debugging.  [THIS RESOURCE](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) will save you lots of headaches in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another (rougher) method [found here](http://www.contextures.com/Excel-VBA-ComboBox-Lists.html) to do this if you so choose.  Also make sure you define the Sheet name you are sourcing the data from:

```
Sub AddItemsToBox()

    Dim itemcell As Range

    For Each itemcell in Sheets("Source Sheet Name").Range("A1:A5")
        frmAddLineItem.ddlProduct.AddItem itemcell.Value
    Next itemcell

End Sub
```

Comment: This works too but again it looks to just create a drop down list with blank lines.

Comment: @Gek Does your workbook have multiple sheets? Check my edit above and input the correct sheet name.

Comment: You should be able to use the `.List` method @Gek. The problem in your OP was that you did not qualify the correct worksheet object :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Both methods work.  Just depends on preference of usage.

Comment: Yes, both methods work. I just wanted to point out that it's not at all necessary in this case to rely on the `.AddItem` method and that the answer does nto depend on using that method only.  IME, the `.AddItem` method is most useful when inserting or re-arranging values in the list, and also *necessary* to use when working with a multi-column list box which is not linked to a RowRange.  Cheers and + 1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

Using ComboBox, you can use `.List` property of the same to populate worksheet values to combox box.

Check this below example:

```
ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value
```

If you want to use Array,

```
Dim Arr As Variant
Arr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value
ComboBox1.List = Arr
```

Comment: The above works but I still need it to pass in the values from an Array

Answer (score 0):

I am just getting into VBA and I am doing exactly this. I think the way I found is pretty easy and straightforward. I'll share it in case it can help someone

1. Declare variable to store table from Worksheet as "range". Make sure 
   it's outside of sub routines so it can be called by any function

`Dim myTable As Range`

2. Store table values in declared variable. Then select which column (range) of values you want to store in your combo box.

````
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set myTable = Worksheets("dataSheetName").Range("A2:B6")
    Me.myComboBox.List = myTable.Columns(1).Value
End Sub ```
````